# Is there a way to pull data from a rest api endpoint with filter parameters in Fluentd

Tags: rest, fluentd

I'm trying to retrieve audit log data from a rest api endpoint with filter parameters like created_before and created_after using fluentd http pull plugin. I need to dynamically pass the  current timestamp and last polled timestamp as query parameters in the rest api as value to the "url" key within the source plugin in fluentd.conf file. Is there ways to do this?

```xml
<source>
  @type http_pull
  url "https://example.com/api/v4/groups/audit_events?pagination=keyset&per_page=100&order_by=created_at&sort=asc&created_after=2021-05-11T22:18:29Z&created_before=2021-05-21T14:43:00Z&rel=next"
  interval 1s
</source>
```

Comment: When you say "dynamically pass", are you trying to pass those parameters when fluentd starts?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: You can use environment variables for that. Please check fluentd docs. There are other similar questions on SO also.